# What does it mean in Expo when the adb has failed to install?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am new to Expo and I’m trying to figure out how to make an app on an Android device. I have downloaded a lot of software up to this point such as Node.js, vscode, Android Studio, and more. I have gotten far into my program, but when I try to run it by using the Android emulator I made (which is opened in vscode), the emulator opens, but the program doesn’t run and I get the following error:

› Opening on Android…
› Opening emulator S10_EXP_API_33
› Opening exp://[10.156.93.45:19000] on S10_EXP_API_33

```
Error: adb: failed to install C:\Users\aaron.expo\android-apk-cache\Exponent-2.25.2.apk:
Exception occurred while executing ‘install’:
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:595)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3434)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doRunInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1
```

S10_EXP_API_33 is the name of my emulator, and it seems like the program was trying to download Exponent-2.25.2.apk but didn’t work.

What can I do to fix this? Any help is appreciated.